# React Checkbox always returns false after handleFormSubmit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

When I submit my form, the value of "balcony" is always false no matter if checked or not.
In the console.log at the beginning of the render, the state does update to true when I check the box, but POST it as false in the database. All the other values are posted correctly.
What am I missing ?

Here is my code :

```
class AddListing extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: "",
        address: "",
        numberOfRooms: 0,
        sqm: 0,
        balcony: false,
        description: "",
        date: Date.now(),
        uploadErrorMsg:''
    };
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
     this.handleCheckClick = this.handleCheckClick.bind(this);
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
}

handleCheckbox(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
    })
  }

handleCheckClick = () => {
  this.setState({ balcony: !this.state.balcony });
}

handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post(`http://localhost:5555/api/listings`, this.state)
        .then((resp) => {
            console.log("response ====> ", resp)
            this.setState({ title: "", address: "", numberOfRooms: 0, sqm: 0, balcony: false, description: "", date: Date.now() });
            this.props.addListingCallback(resp.data);
        })
}

render() {
    console.log("state", this.state)
    return (
        
        <div>
            <h3>Add Listing:</h3>
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                    <label>Title:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="title" 
                        value={this.state.title} 
                        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
                    <br />
                    <label>Address:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="address" 
                        value={this.state.address} 
                        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
                    <br />
                    <label>Number of rooms:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="number" 
                        name="numberOfRooms" 
                        value={this.state.numberOfRooms} 
                        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
                    <br />
                    <label>sqm:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="number" 
                        name="sqm" 
                        value={this.state.sqm} 
                        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
                    <br />
                    <label>Balcony:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="checkbox" 
                        name="balcony" 
                        checked={this.state.balcony}
                        value={this.state.balcony} 
                        onChange={e => this.handleCheckClick(e)} />
                    <br />
                    <label>Description:</label>
                    <textarea 
                        type="text" 
                        name="description" 
                        value={this.state.description} 
                        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
                    <button name="ADD"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

I also tried the handleCheckbox() method but same results. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have to update state base on a previous state value, you should always pass a function to setState, as setState is asynchronous.

So you should never do this `this.setState({ balcony: !this.state.balcony });`
but do this instead
`this.setState(prevState => { balcony: !prevState.balcony });`

Also, in react, the `checked` attribute is what contains the state of the checkbox not the `value` attribute, so you don't need a value attribute on checkbox input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't seem to fix the problem. Could it come from my listing routes ? 

  router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {      
      Listing.create({
        balcony: req.body.balcony === "on" ? true : false, 
      })
        .then(newListing => {
          res.json(newListing); 
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.json(err);
        });
    });
 (left out the other attributes for clarity)

Comment: Yes it could, you can check the network tab in the devtools to see if the structure the POST request being sent. If it is accurate there, then the problem is a backend one.

Comment: Shouldn't `{ balcony: req.body.balcony === "on" ? true : false, }` just be `{ balcony: req.body.balcony }` ?

Comment: It should indeed ! Everything works now, thank you for ending a 3 days headache :)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the updated state in the handleForSubmit method.

```
Object {title: "", address: "", numberOfRooms: 0, sqm: 0, balcony: true…}
title: ""
address: ""
numberOfRooms: 0
sqm: 0
balcony: true
description: ""
date: 1601488407603
uploadErrorMsg: ""
```

The issue might be because of resetting the state after the post response.

Code base:- https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-jang-qhs8r?file=/src/addListing.js